# Can't use LWC in Email Template when using @wire method

Tags: lightning-web-components, email, email-template, html

I'm trying to use a lightning web component in an email template. I'd like to be able to set variables based on the state of the related object. As soon as I add reference to @wire, the email template can't be saved. Is this just not supported in email templates? Preferably I'd like to connect an APEX method, but that's also not working.

Not working:

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire} from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Offer__c.Type__c';
import VERSION_TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Offer__c.Version_Type__c';

export default class IsoOfferEmailStips extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    offer;
    isUpdated = false;
    isSoftOffer = false;  
}
```

working

```
import { LightningElement,api} from 'lwc';

export default class IsoOfferEmailStips extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    offer;
    isUpdated = false;
    isSoftOffer = false;   
}
```

Any guidance?

EDIT:
Turns out @wire and apex methods are not supported in Email Templates.

Comment: Have you reviewed [Considerations for Custom Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_email_builder_custom_components_tips)

Comment: Based on the question edit , I've posted the documentation details as comment so it can help others in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Considerations for Custom Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_email_builder_custom_components_tips) ,

> Unsupported Items:
> The rendering engine that powers our content
> builder is run in a secure environment. However, there are limits on
> what code you can add in the custom component files.
>
> - Any type of DOM API
> - The renderedCallback() lifecycle hook in .js file
> - The Web API fetch() method in .js files
> - tags in .html files
> - References to the window object in .js files
> - Base components in the lightning namespace
> - The wire service using the @wire syntax
> - Apex methods, except for PicklistEntry

As you see, @wire and apex methods are not supported in Email Templates.